# Non-existence of expectation but existence of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard Gaussian random variables, i.e,  $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$. It is a well known fact that the ratio $X/Y$ follows a Cauchy distribution and does not have a mean. Suppose the ratio is denoted by $Z$ as follows:
$$
Z \triangleq \frac{X}{Y}.
$$
Can we say that $E[Z|Y]=0$? Or does conditional expectation of $Z$ given $Y$ does not exist at all?

All the references that I have come across assume that expectation of the random variable is well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

We can't, really, no; since $Z$ doesn't have finite expectation, conditional expectation isn't technically well-defined.

The main issue is that it depends dramatically on how you define $E[Z | Y]$.  For instance, if you define $E[Z | Y = y] = \lim_{h \to 0^+} E[Z | Y \in [y - h,y+h]]$ for $y \neq 0$, then you'd indeed have $E[Z | Y = y] = 0$.  As it stands, conditional expectation isn't defined this way, and only makes sense for random variables with finite expectation (more precisely, random variables in $L^1$).

Comment: Does law of iterated expectation continue to hold with above definition? I feel that it shouldn't since $E[Z]$ is undefined and so we cannot claim $E[Z]=E[E[Z|Y]]=E[0]=0$ which obviously isn't true.

Comment: @pikachuchameleon, no it doesn't, as you note.

Comment: Then I guess $E[f(Z)|Y]$ is also not defined even if $f$ is well-behaved, such as projection onto unit interval etc.?